# Is there a VPN kill switch on Linux for OpenVPN?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I tried using ExpressVPN but that didnt work so I use openVPN now trough terminal. I use it a lot for Tor and want to make sure nothing happens. Is there a kill switch or icon on the status bar that shows VPN connectivity?

Comment: If you haven't changed your icon set, the network icon in the top panel should show a padlock icon along with the network icon.